# BFS implementation to find connected components taking too long

Tags: java, performance, breadth-first-search, graph

This is in continuation to a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256966/deriving-a-group-or-a-set-from-a-map).  Given the total number of nodes (employees) and the adjacency list (friendship amongst employees), I need to find all the connected components.

```
public class Main {
    static HashMap<String, Set<String>> friendShips;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader  in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String dataLine = in.readLine();
            String[] lineParts = dataLine.split(" ");
            int employeeCount = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[0]);
            int friendShipCount = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[1]);
            friendShips = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < friendShipCount; i++) {
                String friendShipLine = in.readLine();
                String[] friendParts = friendShipLine.split(" ");
                mapFriends(friendParts[0], friendParts[1], friendShips);
                mapFriends(friendParts[1], friendParts[0], friendShips);
            }
            Set<String> employees = new HashSet<String>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= employeeCount; i++) {
                employees.add(Integer.toString(i));
            }
            Vector<Set<String>> friendBuckets = bucketizeEmployees(employees);
            System.out.println(friendBuckets.size());
    }

    public static void mapFriends(String friendA, String friendB, Map<String, Set<String>> friendsShipMap) {
        if (friendsShipMap.containsKey(friendA)) {
            friendsShipMap.get(friendA).add(friendB);
        } else {
            Set<String> friends = new HashSet<String>();
            friends.add(friendB);
            friendsShipMap.put(friendA, friends);
        }
    }

    public static Vector<Set<String>> bucketizeEmployees(Set<String> employees) {
        Vector<Set<String>> friendBuckets = new Vector<Set<String>>();
        while (!employees.isEmpty()) {
            String employee = getHeadElement(employees);
            Set<String> connectedEmployeesBucket = getConnectedFriends(employee);
            friendBuckets.add(connectedEmployeesBucket);
            employees.removeAll(connectedEmployeesBucket);
        }
        return friendBuckets;
    }

    private static Set<String> getConnectedFriends(String friend) {
        Set<String> connectedFriends = new HashSet<String>();
        connectedFriends.add(friend);
        Set<String> queuedFriends = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        if (friendShips.get(friend) != null) {
            queuedFriends.addAll(friendShips.get(friend));
        }
        while (!queuedFriends.isEmpty()) {
            String poppedFriend = getHeadElement(queuedFriends);
            connectedFriends.add(poppedFriend);
            if (friendShips.containsKey(poppedFriend))
                for (String directFriend : friendShips.get(poppedFriend)) {
                    if (!connectedFriends.contains(directFriend) && !queuedFriends.contains(directFriend)) {
                        queuedFriends.add(directFriend);
                    }
                }
        }
        return connectedFriends;
    }

    private static String getHeadElement(Set<String> setFriends) {
        Iterator<String> iter = setFriends.iterator();
        String head = iter.next();
        iter.remove();
        return head;
    }
}
```

I have tested my code using the following script, the results of which I consume as sdtIn

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "100000 100000"
for i in {1..100000}
do
    r1=$(( $RANDOM % 100000 ))
    r2=$(( $RANDOM % 100000 ))
    echo "$r1 $r2"
   done
```

While I was able to verify (for trivial inputs) that my answer is correct, when I try with huge inputs as with the above script, I see that the run takes long (~20s).

Is there anything I can do better in my implementation ?

Comment: Use a profiler to profile the code and find out where you spent the time. It is hard to guess, because a lot is happening there.

Comment: The code is pretty fast, the server JDK (using command line parameter -server) is 2 times faster on my PC (C2D E7200) 12sec vs 24sec.

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all, two things to read or search for: Cluster analysis (just a hint, I'm not an expert about that) and [*Linked: The New Science of Networks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked:_The_New_Science_of_Networks) by *Albert-László Barabási*.

   Barabási in his book shows that networks usually have some nodes which have a lot more connections than the others. The distribution is not the same in the real world as the sample shell script generates.
2. The code is quite good, I like your variable and method names and separated methods. I wonder why haven't anyone reviewed it yet.
3. > ```
   > Vector<Set<String>> friendBuckets = bucketizeEmployees(employees);
   > ```

   I'd use a simple `List` or `ArrayList` here. [Vector is considered obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/843804).
4. In the `getConnectedFriends` method the

   > ```
   > Set<String> queuedFriends = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
   > ```

   could be a [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). It has a [`poll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll%28%29) method. As far as I tested it's faster than the currently used iterator-based remove.
5. > ```
   > public class Main {
   > ```

   `Main` isn't a good class name. Everyone can have a `Main`. What's it purpose? Try to find a more descriptive name.
6. > ```
   > static HashMap<String, Set<String>> friendShips;
   > ```

   `HashMap<...>` reference types should be simply `Map<...>`. See: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*

   [Should I always use the private access modifier for class fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484845/should-i-always-use-the-private-access-modifier-for-class-fields); *Item 13* of *Effective Java 2nd Edition*: *Minimize the accessibility of classes and members*.
7. > ```
   >  static HashMap<String, Set<String>> friendShips;
   > ```

   Instead of `Map<String, Set<String>>` you could use Guava's `Multimap` ([doc](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap), [javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)) which was designed exactly for that. It would reduce the size of the `mapFriends` method:

   ```
   public static void mapFriends(final String friendA, final String friendB,
           final Multimap<String, String> friendsShipMap) {
       friendsShipMap.put(friendA, friendB);
   }
   ```

   So, it could be removed.
8. > ```
   > public static Vector<Set<String>> bucketizeEmployees(Set<String> employees) {
   >     ...
   > }
   > ```

   This method calls `getConnectedFriends(employee)`, which is the following:

   > ```
   > private static Set<String> getConnectedFriends(String friend) {
   >     ...
   > }
   > ```

   It's confusing: what is the difference between an employee and friend? Are they the same?
9. > ```
   > if (friendShips.get(friend) != null) {
   > ```

   The following is the same:

   ```
   if (friendShips.containsKey(friend)) {
   ```

   A [guard clause](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) would be even better.

   ```
   if (!friendShips.containsKey(friend)) {
       return connectedFriends;
   }
   ```
10. > ```
    > if (!connectedFriends.contains(directFriend) && !queuedFriends.contains(directFriend)) {
    >     queuedFriends.add(directFriend);
    > }
    > ```

    The `!queuedFriends.contains(directFriend)` condition is unnecessary, it's a set which can't contain elements twice and adding an already added element to a `LinkedHashSet` doesn't modify anything. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

    > Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set.
11. The following pattern occurs more than once in the code:

    ```
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        String value = map.get(key);
        ...
    }
    ...
    ```

    It might be a microoptimization, but if you profile the code and the results shows it as a bottleneck the following structure is the same:

    ```
    String value = map.get(key);        
    if (value != null) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    ```
12. A few [guard clause](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) would help to make `getConnectedFriends` more flatten:

    ```
    while (!queuedFriends.isEmpty()) {
        final String poppedFriend = getHeadElement(queuedFriends);
        connectedFriends.add(poppedFriend);
        if (!friendShips.containsKey(poppedFriend)) {
            continue;
        }
        for (final String directFriend: friendShips.get(poppedFriend)) {
            if (connectedFriends.contains(directFriend)) {
                continue;
            }
            queuedFriends.add(directFriend);
        }
    }
    ```